# what is the difference between window.unload and window.onunload

Tags: javascript

I've tested both of them and they work as expected in Opera, IE, FF and Chrome. I've searched `window.unload` on google and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=window.unload but it didn't help much. What is the difference between them or `window.unload` is just the older version of `window.onunload`?

Answer (score 0):

`window.onunload` is event handler. When you, or user, call `window.unload`, the event is triggered and `window.onunload` is called. So you can redefine `window.onunload` any way you like to, for example, display a confirmation dialog before unloading, send some data to the server of whatever else.